# long to HWND (VS8 C++)

Tags: casting, long-integer, hwnd

How can I cast long to HWND (C++ visual studio 8)?

```
Long lWindowHandler;
HWND oHwnd = (HWND)lWindowHandler;
```

But I got the following warning:

> warning C4312: 'type cast' : conversion from 'LONG' to 'HWND' of greater size

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HWND is a handle to a window.
This type is declared in WinDef.h as follows:

> typedef HANDLE HWND;

HANDLE is handle to an object.
This type is declared in WinNT.h as follows:

> typedef PVOID HANDLE;

Finally, PVOID is a pointer to any type.
This type is declared in WinNT.h as follows:

> typedef void *PVOID;

So, HWND is actually a pointer to void. You can cast a long to a HWND like this:

> HWND h = (HWND)my_long_var;

but very careful of what information is stored in my_long_var. You have to make sure that you have a pointer in there.

Later edit:
The warning suggest that you've got 64-bit portability checks turned on. If you're building a 32 bit application you can ignore them.

Answer (score 10):

As long as you're sure that the LONG you have is really an HWND, then it's as simple as:

```
HWND hWnd = (HWND)(LONG_PTR)lParam;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I tried that and got a warning:
warning C4312: 'type cast' : conversion from 'LONG' to 'HWND' of greater size
any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: I think this is the best answer, `(HWND) long_ver` does not work for me!

Answer (score 5):

Doing that is only safe if you are not running on a 64 bit version of windows. The LONG type is 32 bits, but the HANDLE type is probably 64 bits. You'll need to make your code 64 bit clean. In short, you will want to change the LONG to a LONG_PTR.

[Rules for using pointer types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384242(VS.85).aspx):

> Do not cast pointers to int, long,
>   ULONG, or DWORD. If you must cast a
>   pointer to test some bits, set or
>   clear bits, or otherwise manipulate
>   its contents, use the UINT_PTR or
>   INT_PTR type. These types are integral
>   types that scale to the size of a
>   pointer for both 32- and 64-bit
>   Windows (for example, ULONG for 32-bit
>   Windows and _int64 for 64-bit
>   Windows). For example, assume you are
>   porting the following code:
>
> ImageBase = (PVOID)((ULONG)ImageBase |
>   1);
>
> As a part of the porting process, you
>   would change the code as follows:
>
> ImageBase =
>   (PVOID)((ULONG_PTR)ImageBase | 1);
>
> Use UINT_PTR and INT_PTR where
>   appropriate (and if you are uncertain
>   whether they are required, there is no
>   harm in using them just in case). Do
>   not cast your pointers to the types
>   ULONG, LONG, INT, UINT, or DWORD.
>
> Note that HANDLE is defined as a
>   void*, so typecasting a HANDLE value
>   to a ULONG value to test, set, or
>   clear the low-order 2 bits is an error
>   on 64-bit Windows.

Comment: While your advice is correct for pointers, see [this answer on handle lengths](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29526711/2636001) (or [the corresponding MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384203%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))– `HWND` only uses the lowest 32 bits and thus is safe across process bounds.