# Is it safe to change this c-cast to a reinterpret_cast?

Tags: c++, winapi, casting, reinterpret-cast

I'm trying to remove a c-style cast from some code I'm working on, and I have concerns about the only alternative.

The original code was:

```
WPARAM param = (WPARAM)(GetDlgItem(IDC_WORKFLOW).m_hWnd);
this->PostMessage(WM_NEXTDLGCTL, param, TRUE);
```

If I use a static cast:

```
WPARAM param = static_cast<WPARAM>(GetDlgItem(IDC_WORKFLOW).m_hWnd);
this->PostMessage(WM_NEXTDLGCTL, param, TRUE);
```

I get the error, 'static_cast' : cannot convert from 'HWND' to 'WPARAM', because there's no valid conversion between the underlying types. This leaves me with "the devil's option":

```
WPARAM param = reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(GetDlgItem(IDC_WORKFLOW).m_hWnd);
this->PostMessage(WM_NEXTDLGCTL, param, TRUE);
```

As I understand it, if a static_cast is impossible, and this isn't related to constness, the C-cast must be doing a reinterpret_cast anyway, which means that the underlying code must be casting back, [which means this is safe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0w9f63b.aspx) (point 3 in remarks). But I'd like to confirm this, before just changing the code.

**Is this cast safe in this specific instance, and how do I confirm this? If not, what is the alternative?**

Comment: Yes it is safe, however you can just keep using C-style cast which is common in Windows API / MFC code, and IMO, is easier to read.

Comment: As safe as casting an integer type to a `void *`.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis WPARAM is guaranteed to be the same width as a pointer, so no problem here

Comment: @dsi I dislike using C-Style because it hides the bad thing you're doing, but thanks for pointing out that it is a common pattern in the codebase I'm working with.

Comment: @dsi Incidentally, could you make that an answer? If nothing better than that comes up, it'd be a "good enough" for anyone searching for this kind of question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is safe, because `WPARAM` is defined as:

```
typedef UINT_PTR            WPARAM;
```

and _PTR suffix means the type is big enough to hold a pointer.

while HWND is:

```
 typedef HANDLE HWND;
```

where HANDLE is:

```
typedef void *HANDLE;
```

so size of void* and UINT_PTR are always the same. If you would store it in 64bit application and try read in 32 bit application, then you would get in trouble.

if you are still concenred if that is safe to do such casts, you can search Visual Studio sources (in  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\ folder), and you will find lots of lines with `reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(...)` and `reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(...)`.

Comment: You can safely store 64 bits HWND in 32 bits types. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18266626/what-is-windows-handle-range-on-a-64-bits-application

Comment: If `STRICT` is defined then `HWND` is a typedef for `struct HWND__*` instead of `HANDLE`/`void*`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes, but its still a pointer value, no one is dereferencing HWND. The whole DECLARE_HANDLE is only to add some typesafety to windows handles.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is fine, and is what `reinterpret_cast` is intended for, ie the "trust me I know what I'm doing" approach that C has to casting.

Answer (score 1):

maybe now we can use `std::bit_cast` from C++20 as an alternative way, which should be more well-behaved.

under the hood, `std::bit_cast` uses `std::memcpy`, which I think you can also use to cast from `HWND` to `WPARAM`

Answer (score 0):

It might work on your computer, with your compiler, and with a very specific set of compilation options for your compiler.

You are casting one pointer type to another. That is not "safe". Your code is violating the strict aliasing rule. This enables your compiler to interpret your code in ways very different from what you intended. Your code might work, it might not. You are invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: While true, in this specific instance, as other answers have said, this is the only way to achieve the result needed.

Comment: Also, it's not undefined. The behaviour is well-defined for the basic "cast-to-X", "cast-back-from-X", which is what reinterpret_cast is for. Actually *using* the WPARAM without casting back to a handle is an entirely different matter, which is why I asked the question.

Answer (score 0):

No as a general rule. The C style cast will try to do what is right. This normally means trying a `static_cast` and only if this is impossible doing a `reinterpret_cast`

Take a look at the following C++ code

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <new>

class Base
{
public:
    int base;
};

class Extension
{
public:
    int extension;
};

class Derived : public Base, public Extension
{
public:
    int derived;
};

int main()
{
    Derived* der = new Derived;
    der->base = 1;
    der->extension = 2;
    der->derived = 3;

    Extension* ext = (Extension*)der;
    printf ("The value of ext->extension = %d\n",ext->extension);
    ext = reinterpret_cast<Extension*>(der);  
    printf ("The value of ext->extension = %d\n",ext->extension);
}
```

The results are

```
c:\work>test
The value of ext->extension = 2    
The value of ext->extension = 1
```

In other words it is not safe to blindly replace C style casts with reinterpret_casts.

Comment: Thanks and good answer for the general case, but I'm aware of the risks of what I termed "the devil's option", I'm asking about this specific case, so that I'm **not** doing it blindly.